# How to get QTabWidget title text of QWidget in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I know I can use the widget function of QTabWidget in order to get the the QPlanTextEdit from the specified tab. But how can I get the tab title text of the current tab widget?

```
QPlainTextEdit* pTextEdit = NULL;
QWidget* pWidget= ui->tabWidget->widget(1);
if (pWidget->metaObject()->className() == "QPlainTextEdit")
    pTextEdit = (QPlainTextEdit*)pWidget;
else
{
    QList<QPlainTextEdit *> allTextEdits = pWidget->findChildren<QPlainTextEdit *>();
    if (allTextEdits.count() != 1)
    { 
        qError() << "Error";
        return;
    }  
    pTextEdit = allTextEdits[0];
}
ptextEdit->setPlainText("Updated Plain Text Edit);
// HERE I NEED THE CURRENT TAB'S TEXT!!
```

Comment: Are you looking for the text of current tab label? http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html#tabText

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
int index = ui->tabWidget->currentIndex();
QString currentTabText = ui->tabWidget->tabText(index);
```