# How did I get QTabWidget name on change?

Tags: python, qtabwidget

Using Event/Callback so far I have only been able to get the index...How do I get the name of the tab?

```
self.tabWidget.currentChanged.connect(self.change_sheet)

def change_sheet(self,signal):
      print(self.tabWidget.currentIndex())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it in C++ : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34604817/11384184
The translation to Python will be simple :

```py
name = self.tabWidget.tabText(self.tabWidget.currentIndex())
```

Comment: Thank you...that did it!

Comment: @ScottCov then you can mark the answar as "accepted" ;-)